# Can't read child of object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am unsure how to read the the properties, I have this javascript function defined

```
function Criteria(object1, object2, object3, object4) {
    var self = this;
    self.object1 = ko.observable(object1);
    self.object2 = ko.observable(object2);
    self.object3 = ko.observable(object3);
    self.object4 = ko.observable(object4);
}
```

Then I define my main view modle as follow

```
   var vmBudget = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.criterias = ko.observableArray();
        this.initialize = function () {
          self.criterias.push(new Criteria("test","","",""));
          self.criterias.push(new Criteria("", "test2", "", ""));
        };
        alert(JSON.stringify(self.criterias()[0].object1()));
   }
```

On my html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var vm = new vmBudget();
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("L09budget"));
        vm.initialize();
    });
</script>
```

Once I have the variablie Initialie the json is {}, I am expecting a Json like

```
{
Object1: ""
Object2: ""
Object3: ""
Object4: ""
}
```

Comment: self.criterias seems to be an array, but you are accessing it as if you were calling a function, ie self.criterias().  Perhaps try alert(JSON.stringify(self.criterias[0].object1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alert is firing before your initialize pushes anything into the criterias array, so yes `criterias()[0]` is undefined at that point.

If you move the alert into the initialize function so that it happens after the items get pushed into the array you should see your expected data.

```js
function Criteria(object1, object2, object3, object4) {
   var self = this;
   self.object1 = ko.observable(object1);
   self.object2 = ko.observable(object2);
   self.object3 = ko.observable(object3);
   self.object4 = ko.observable(object4);
}

var vmBudget = function() {
   var self = this;
   this.criterias = ko.observableArray();
   this.initialize = function() {
      self.criterias.push(new Criteria("test", "", "", ""));
      self.criterias.push(new Criteria("", "test2", "", ""));
      alert(JSON.stringify(self.criterias()[0].object1()));
   };
}

var vm = new vmBudget();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```